# How to install IIS10 and Dotnet4.6.2 with user data while creating AWS windows server

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, .net-4.6.2, ec2-userdata

In AWS, I need to automate AWS windows server 2019 installation using Terraform Script.

Inside that AWS windows server, I need to Enable IIS10 and install ASP .NET 4.6.2.

I need to add user data(using PowerShell script) to Enable IIS10 and install ASP .NET 4.6.2.

I have used below userdata in terraform script to Enable IIS10 and install ASP .NET 4.6.2.

```
# Bootstrapping PowerShell Script
data "template_file" "windows-userdata" {
  template = <<EOF
<powershell>
# Install IIS
Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools;
# Install DotNet 4.6
Install-WindowsFeature .NET-Framework-46-Features;
# Restart machine
shutdown -r -t 10;
</powershell>
EOF
}
```

Everything is working fine but I am unable to install .Net4.6.2. It is installing .Net4.8.

Can anyone please tell me, Is there any way to install ASP .Net4.6.2 using userdata(PowerShell script)?

I need to install ASP .Net4.6.2 version.

Comment: Are you sure .Net 4.6 is available in that release of Windows Server 2019?

Comment: Okay thankyou Dennis. I got it. For windows server 2019, DotNet 4.8 and 4.7.2 is the compatibility version.